# 100% Width causes div to go off screen while in container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, containers

So I'm having a little trouble aligning my div in the container with Bootstrap.

What I'm trying to do is get the div to extend full width inside the container width.

It works on the left side of the container but it doesn't on the right. It goes off-screen.

HTML:

```
<!-- Image With Action Section -->
    <section class="special_section">
        <div class="container-fluid" style="max-height: 25%">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="caption-2">
                        <img src="background-image-url" class="img-full-width img-responsive" alt="" />
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="action-footer">
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <h4 class="caption-text">Title</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    Link
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4>Title</h4>
                                <p>Content</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

CSS:

```
.caption-2 .action-footer {
    margin: -1px 0 0 0;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
@media (min-width:500px) {
    .caption-2 .action-footer {
        margin:0;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 10%;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.action-footer .col-md-12 {
    margin-top: -10px;
}
```

The `.action-footer` div is the one that I need to be 100% width inside the parent container. Instead it get's way too much width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're main problem is actually here:

```
@media (min-width:500px) {
    .caption-2 .action-footer {
        margin:0;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 10%;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Change it to:  `position: relative;` Having in mind that you are building this for mobile, it should do the job. Whenever using **container-fluid**, most of the elements have a **relative** position so they can re-align with the screen width.

Comment: Right, this actually makes it the correct width, the only problem now is that the div moves under the image instead of being on it, but it is the correct solution. Thank you!

Comment: @Chris I think that is a new problem entirely on its own. Try re-arranging your code or use **z-index** for positioning one element over the other.

Answer (score 13):

You need to apply CSS property `box-sizing: border-box;`

```
.action-footer {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Bootstrap automatically applies that to all elements. So that won't work unfortunately

Comment: This was my issue. I applied this style to all of my elements and my elements no longer go off the page with `width: 100%`. I wonder why this even exists...

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the order of `container` and `action-footer` to get the desired result also added `left:0px` to `ation-footer` so it always start from left of body.

```
@media (min-width:500px) {
  .caption-2 .action-footer {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    left:0px;
  }
}
```

> Here is the working code:

```css
.caption-2 .action-footer {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

@media (min-width:500px) {
  .caption-2 .action-footer {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    left:0px;
  }
}

.action-footer .col-md-12 {
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="special_section">
  <div class="container-fluid" style="max-height: 25%">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="caption-2">
          <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150" class="img-full-width img-responsive" alt="" />
          <div class="action-footer">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <h4 class="caption-text">Title</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-2">
                Link
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
            <div class="caption">
              <h4>Title</h4>
              <p>Content</p>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```